# sendSignInLinkToEmail sending invalid URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement firebase's [email link auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) on a **web app** and I'm having some trouble understanding what the problem here is.

I've followed their instructions on the page to send the email and it's sending, but the problem is the URL being sent is an invalid one.

```
async sendAuthEmail(email) {
  var actionCodeSettings = {
    // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
    // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
    url: "http://localhost:3000",
    // This must be true.
    handleCodeInApp: true,
    iOS: {
      bundleId: "com.example.ios"
    },
    android: {
      packageName: "com.example.android",
      installApp: true,
      minimumVersion: "12"
    }
  };

  return await firebase
    .auth()
    .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings);
}
```

And the URL being sent is (I changed my firebaseapp name):

```
https://?link=https://myfirebasedbname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIzaSyDSio7vAbW7O0TVGCF2UpG7FsQDvHX0M7Q%26mode%3DsignIn%26oobCode%3DXoAsz5CoIJOhdhAcJpC2E3iWI8fmyTwJPIUmMlgLvakAAAFiy0Wm9A%26continueUrl%3Dhttp://localhost:3000&apn=com.example.android&amv=12&ibi=com.example.ios&ifl=https://myfirebasedbname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIzaSyDSio7vAbW7O0TVGCF2UpG7FsQDvHX0M7Q%26mode%3DsignIn%26oobCode%3DXoAsz5CoIJOhdhAcJpC2E3iWI8fmyTwJPIUmMlgLvakAAAFiy0Wm9A%26continueUrl%3Dhttp://localhost:3000
```

I also tried changing the `url` parameter but it fails anyway.

Any ideas that can be shared?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you configured your Firebase Dynamic Link domain? You need to do that in the dynamic links section of the Firebase Console.

If you are only using this for a web only app, you don' t need to include the `android` or `ios` fields in the `ActionCodeSettings` object. This avoids the need to setup FDL:

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true
};
```

Comment: Hello bojeil and thank you or your reply. Is this necessary even for mobile? I ask this because this is strictly a web app.

Comment: Then remove the android and iOS part. Just include the `url` and the `handleCodeInApp` set to `true`. When you pass the former, it is assumed you want to support mobile flows.

Comment: Thank you so much bojeil. Please update your answer to include the removal of android and iOS keys in the json.